# Programming exercises to accommodate the Art of Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, hla

I have been learning High Level Assembly (HLA) via the book [Art of Assembly](http://nostarch.com/assembly2.htm), which is meant to use high level language constructs to introduce concepts of assembly language.

The problem is while I seem to understand quite a lot of what is in the book the book contains no exercises or problems. Where then can I find a collection of problems suited to assembly language?

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a version of AoAL available at the following URL that does include laboratory exercises:

http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/DOS/pdf/0_AoAPDF.html

Otherwise, google around and look at the various university courses.  Virtually every university CS program has an assembly language class.  Often, these classes will have websites that include the actual homework assigned for that class, and sometimes, they'll even have solutions.  If they do not have solutions posted, you can probably just email the professor and he'll probably send them to you.

Comment: I saw that version, but it isn't terribly useful to me as a) it's for the 16 bit version and b) it assumes familiarity with a higher level language like C++, which I don't really have.

Comment: Familiarity with at least BASIC if not C would be first on my list of things to learn before playing with assembler.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: I disagree. No knowledge of any other language will help in learning an assembly language. This is a myth.

Comment: Then we agree to disagree.  I'd rather have a higher level language (with a higher level debugger) then have to puzzle through the crap most assemblers kick out on error.  Also, having for/while/do/if instead of compare/jmp makes it plain easier to learn basic programming concepts.  Yes, they are all gotos at the bottom level, but why learn "bad" habits early if you don't need to?  I could go on, but I think we agree to disagree here.

Comment: Note that currently the provided link is dead.

Comment: could you update the link as it is offline atm! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can look at [someone's else](http://vx.netlux.org/) ASM code or even binaries (you can use [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download.shtml) for this). Tiny old viruses usually were written to take as little space as possible, so there are many nonstandard uses of instructions and of coding styles.

Comment: could you update first link as it is offline atm! Thank you